# Slow WiFi since updating to 18.04

Tags: networking, wireless, internet

I've had some weird internet issues since upgrading.

First of all, my wifi USB dongle stopped working so I thought it was broken, I replaced it and was getting speeds of under 1 Mbps.

Since then I have had very poor download speeds, and surfing has been a bit hit and miss with some sites loading instantly, and others crawling. everything was fine using the same hardware on 16.04

What can I do to speed things up?

Thanks!

Comment: Hi Syteanric, can you add some more information to your question? 1) The output of `dmesg | grep Linux` 2) The output of `lshw -C network` 3) The output of `lsusb`

Answer (score 25):

I just fixed this on ubuntu 18.04 - turns out there is some kind of issue with 802.11n and iwlwifi Intel chips. The solution is to turn it off. 

Check if it works first with:

```
sudo modprobe -r iwlwifi

sudo modprobe iwlwifi 11n_disable=1
```

Make it permanent with this command:

```
echo "options iwlwifi 11n_disable=1" | sudo tee /etc/modprobe.d/iwlwifi.conf
```

I did this and my wifi speeds instantly went back to normal.

Comment: This disables support for n-band wireless connections, correct?  That should be noted in this answer if so.

https://wiki.debian.org/iwlwifi

Comment: I changed the value 11n_disable=10  for obtaining maximum speeds on my Intel Wifi 5000 series card ... (Dell E6500 Latitude standard wifi card) . Also I turned off the 5Ghz option (dualband 2.4 / 5 Ghz) in the routersoftware and forced 1 channel only instead of automatic. This solved totally my problems with iwlwifi driver and dropping speeds . I did not tweak the powersave function (so as it is with Ubuntu ootb) .

Comment: This worked like a charm. Thanks man!

Comment: But after sometime it went to past

Answer (score 0):

> I just fixed this on ubuntu 18.04 - turns out there is some kind of issue with 802.11n and iwlwifi Intel chips.

That's for sure 8-) !  With a Advanced-N 6200 in a computer I just picked up, I was getting freezes (no LEDs so I don't know if the kernel paniced..) within a minute or two once I started rsync'ing some files over.  11n_disable=1 solved this for me.

Update: Actually I had freezes with 11n_disable=1 also; I popped my case open and found the card was not fully seated!