# Ubuntu 18.04 slow connection requests

Tags: networking, internet, 18.04

I just updated my T450s to Ubuntu 18.04 LTS and since then the connection request time is just horrible. If I make any connection to the internet, be it curl, ping or a normal website call it takes 3-5 seconds before anything happens. Only then the actuall connection is being established.

What I tried so far:

- It is intependend of medium (WIFI/ Cable)
- It is not the DNS as a ping to e.g. 8.8.8.8 still takes time before it starts after pressing enter
- It is not the internet connection itself as I can download and upload with full speed and its the same issue on LAN
- It is not a networek isuue as my dekstop computer and phone do not have this issue
- It is not a hardware issue with the laptop as the problem does not persist with a live booted Ubuntu 18.04.

I'm pretty clueless as to what the issue is and even more so how to debug it properly. I ran strace with the ' -T ' for ping and could identify some calls that are repeatedly taking ~ one second. But I don't know enough about the internals of linux to understand that. I can post said output if neccessary.

Thanks for any help in advance

Comment: anybody? It's really bothering me

Comment: this worked for me: https://askubuntu.com/questions/1029723/slow-wifi-since-updating-to-18-04