# Ubuntu 18.04.2 LTS Bandwidth Throttling?

Tags: networking, bandwidth

Ubuntu 18.04.2 LTS New Install: Upload Bandwith ~4 Mbit/s 
Ubuntu 16.04 LTS New Install: Upload Bandwith ~100 Mbit/s 
After Dist Upgrade from 16.04 to 18.04.02 LTS: Upload Bandwith: ~4 Mbit/s

**speedtest-cli**

Testing download speed 
Download: 50.85 Mbit/s 
Testing upload speed 
Upload: 4.10 Mbit/s

Is there some kind of throttling activated in Ubuntu 18.04.2 LTS? I used always the same networking settings.

```
$ lshw -C network
  *-network
       description: Ethernet interface
       product: VMXNET3 Ethernet Controller
       vendor: VMware
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:03:00.0
       logical name: ens160
       version: 01       
       size: 10Gbit/s
       capacity: 10Gbit/s
       width: 32 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm pciexpress msi msix bus_master cap_list rom ethernet physical logical tp 1000bt-fd 10000bt-fd
       configuration: autonegotiation=off broadcast=yes driver=vmxnet3 driverversion=1.4.14.0-k-NAPI duplex=full ip=xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx latency=0 link=yes multicast=yes port=twisted pair speed=10Gbit/s
       resources: irq:18 memory:fd4fc000-fd4fcfff memory:fd4fd000-fd4fdfff memory:fd4fe000-fd4fffff ioport:4000(size=16) memory:fd400000-fd40ffff
```

Comment: Nope. You would know if there is throttling: you would have installed "wondershaper" and configured it yourself ;) Did you see https://askubuntu.com/questions/1029723/slow-wifi-since-updating-to-18-04 and check if you have that issue?

Comment: Yeah, i know. But wondersharper is not installed. Unfortunatley it is not an issue with wifi, it is a virtual machine.

Comment: [This is a known issue with speedtest-cli](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1159807/slow-upload-speed-on-machine-running-ubuntu-server-18-04)