# Slow upload speed on machine running Ubuntu Server 18.04

Tags: networking, server, internet

I'm currently running Ubuntu Server 18.04 on a home server build to act as a Plex server, among other things. I have it connected via ethernet (with a 5-port switch between it and the router), and get download speeds consistently in the 750-900 MBit/s range when running `speedtest-cli`, which is expected. However, the upload speed has never gone above 5 MBit/s, despite every other machine in the house getting speeds around 300-400 or more when performing speedtests.

How can I diagnose what might be causing these slow upload speeds? I'm unsure what might be causing the issue if other devices are having no trouble on the same network, including another computer that is connected to the same 5-port switch. I tried basic things like resetting the router and swapping cables and ports on the switch but that did not change anything.

Edit: Added network controller info

```
00:14.3 Network controller: Intel Corporation Wireless-AC 9560 [Jefferson Peak] (rev 10)
00:1f.6 Ethernet controller: Intel Corporation Ethernet Connection (7) I219-V (rev 10)
```

Edit 2: It's possible this might be an issue with `speedtest-cli`. I've found two separate issues on the github discussing slow upload speed results.

[Thread 1](https://github.com/sivel/speedtest-cli/issues/13)

[Thread 2](https://github.com/sivel/speedtest-cli/issues/263)

I'll try to use an alternative method to test and see what the result is.

Edit 3: I just confirmed that `speedtest-cli` is indeed broken for upload speeds. I found [this article](https://www.techrepublic.com/article/how-to-run-a-network-speed-test-from-a-headless-linux-server/) that point to a different script for testing speeds, and was able to get results consistent with my network speeds.

Comment: Welcome to [ubuntu.se]!  **:-)** Please [edit] your question and provide the output of `lspci | grep --ignore-case network`

Comment: @OstrichGlue thank you for sharing your solution. I had the same issue with `speedtest-cli` and the Python script worked :-)